# running complied erlang app yields a crash dump erlang_guidelines

Tags: erlang, rebar

I am trying to run a compiled erlang beam file from https://github.com/elbrujohalcon/erlang_guidelines

but it crash dumps for some reason. I'm actually not quite sure how to run the example applications using rebar or erl directly (not rebar3, I am on CentOS 7 with EPEL-release version of erlang, which is probably not recommended right?).

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: As per [the compatibility section in the documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/system_principles/misc.html#compatibility), beam files are guaranteed to be loadable on the Erlang release they were compiled on (obviously) and two subsequent major releases. Perhaps you're using a different Erlang version from the one used to compile these beam files? If not, the first line of the crash dump will usually be helpful in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the latest erlang from [erlang solutions downloads](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/) and removed the epel-release version of erlang and it's dependencies; then I installed rebar3 using [rebar3](https://rebar3.readme.io/docs/getting-started) and ran `rebar compile` on erlang_guidelines and it compiles and no longer crash dumps.